# google storage transfer service account does not exist in new project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create resources using Terraform in a new GCP project. As part of that I want to set `roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter` to the Google managed service account which runs storage transfer service jobs (the pattern is `project-[project-number]@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) for a specific bucket. I am using the following config:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_binding" "publisher_bucket_binding" {
  bucket = "${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}"
  members     = ["serviceAccount:project-${var.project_number}@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com"]
  role = "roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter"
}
```

to clarify, I want to do this so that when I create one off transfer jobs using the JSON APIs, it doesn't fail prerequisite checks.

When I run Terraform apply, I get the following:

```
Error applying IAM policy for Storage Bucket "bucket":
Error setting IAM policy for Storage Bucket "bucket": googleapi:
Error 400: Invalid argument, invalid
```

I think this is because the service account in question does not exist yet as I can not do this via the console either.

Is there any other service that I need to enable for the service account to be created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it seems I am able to create/find the service account once I run this:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/get

for my project to get the email address.

not sure if this is the best way but it works..

Comment: Something similar happened to me too when I put in my Project ID instead of Project Number.

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me as well. While digging further I found the same documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/iam-transfer#source-permissions

Comment: A really shitty way to create such a SA... But many thx

Answer (score 1):

Soroosh's reply is accurate, after querying the API as per this DOC: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/ will enable the service account and terraform will run, but now you have to create an api call in terraform for that to work, ain't nobody got time for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following block to execute the get to create the service account

```
data "google_storage_transfer_project_service_account" "default" {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a more generic answer to this that applies all APIs beyond just Storage Transfer API.

From the [provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/project_service_identity):

```
data "google_project" "project" {}

resource "google_project_service_identity" "hc_sa" {
  provider = google-beta

  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  service = "healthcare.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "hc_sa_bq_jobuser" {
  project = data.google_project.project.project_id
  role    = "roles/bigquery.jobUser"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_project_service_identity.hc_sa.email}"
}
```

You should be able to replace `healthcare.googleapis.com` with your specific API, and the identifying email for the service account will be stored in `google_project_service_identity.your_creative_name.email`.  Terraform will now be able to track google-provided service agent accounts and apply roles to them :D